AWS Lambda API Proxy with java SDK written in kotlin works in AWS console tests but fails in postman
We are developing a Crypto Exchange rates API and an application to do that we decided to use AWS Lambda and API gateway to access our DB and send back converted rates as JSON, we used Lambda java SDK and wrote the code, which is working fine and passing tests in AWS console while we do the same from postman we are not getting any input events, so please refer to the code below and point me in any direction possible, thank you.
class CryptoGetter : RequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent> {

    override fun handleRequest(
        input: APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent?,
        context: Context?
    ): APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent {

        if(input?.httpMethod == "GET" ) {

            val pageNumber = input.pathParameters?.get("page") ?: 1

            try {
                val mongoPage: MongoPage = collection.find().first() ?: MongoPage()
                if (mongoPage.pageId.contains("page$pageNumber")) {
                    val index = mongoPage.pageId.indexOf("page$pageNumber")
                    val page = mongoPage.pages[index]
                    return APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent().apply {
                        statusCode = 200
                        withBody(
                            page
                        )
                    }
                } else {
                return APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent().apply {
                    statusCode = 404
                    withBody(
                        "{ \"error\": \"page not found\" }"
                    )
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            return APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent().apply {
                statusCode = 505
                withBody(
                    "{ \"error\": \"error occurred ${e.message}\" }"
                )
            }
        }
        }else if(input?.httpMethod == "POST" || input?.pathParameters?.get("method") == (1).toString()) {
            
             /// post request implementation

        } else {
            return APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent().apply {
                statusCode = 405
                withBody(
                    "Method not allowed, $input"
                )
            }
        }

    }
}

when I test it in AWS Console I get the result as expected it looks like this

but when I try to access it in the postman or any other place input event will be empty and that looks like this

as we can see in the response it shows empty input so we were trying to find why the input wasn't received then after a long search we think that it is getting treated as a normal event and not as a Proxy API event but we aren't sure, so please help us in any way possible,
and in AWS API Gateway it looks like this

